/usr/bin/ld: in function `main.cold': (.text.unlikely+0x11): undefined reference to `QWidget::~QWidget()'
In simple words for I got this problem for several Qtpackages: how to make g++ know what Qt is when using qmake?
When compiling a program I got problems with letting the parts link each other
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2007, Johan Thelin
 * 
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
 *       this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,  
 *       this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation 
 *       and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *     * Neither the name of APress nor the names of its contributors 
 *       may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software 
 *       without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit ();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel ();

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout ();
    layout->addWidget (lineEdit);
    layout->addWidget (label);
    widget.setLayout (layout);

    widget.show ();

    return app.exec ();

brings the error message
$ LC_ALL=C qmake -project; LC_ALL=C qmake; LC_ALL=C make
Info: creating stash file /path/to/my/dir/.qmake.stash
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o build main.o   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main.cold':
main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x11): undefined reference to `QWidget::~QWidget()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x19): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b): undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x37): undefined reference to `QWidget::QWidget(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4e): undefined reference to `QLineEdit::QLineEdit(QWidget*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x67): undefined reference to `QLabel::QLabel(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7c): undefined reference to `QVBoxLayout::QVBoxLayout()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8b): undefined reference to `QBoxLayout::addWidget(QWidget*, int, QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9a): undefined reference to `QBoxLayout::addWidget(QWidget*, int, QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa5): undefined reference to `QWidget::setLayout(QLayout*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xad): undefined reference to `QWidget::show()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb2): undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbc): undefined reference to `QWidget::~QWidget()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc4): undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:142: build] Error 1

whereas changing the include command so that QtWidgets/ is away, it seems that QApplication is spelled wrongly.
$ LC_ALL=C qmake -project; LC_ALL=C qmake; LC_ALL=C make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <QApplication>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:364: main.o] Error 1


QApplication is correct: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html I suspect your .pro was written for Qt4 because of the old copyright message.

Long story short: you need to link with -lQt5Widgets .

@g-m could you just formulate a command (or an answer) out of this?

If you look at the QWidget documentation it tells you the qmake requirement: specifically QT += widgets.  Just add that to your .pro file.  (There's almost certainly a dupe for this somewhere.)

please show a [mre] including your pro file and Qt version

The solution is in the dupe: Instead of qmake -project it needs to be qmake -project 'QT += widgets'
